# Can we use JSON files of Alexa skills for Watson skills?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alexa-skills-kit, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am seeking for json skills for my chatbot training. I found many json files for Alexa skills. Is there any way to use them to create Watson skills?

I also saw posts about creating Alexa skills with Watson Assistant on Apache.  Can we create Watson skills from Alexa skills?

Many thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 1):

First, the mentioned services are different products by different companies and not compatible and with different features. You can [import intents into IBM Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-intents#intents-import) as part of creating a skill. You can also [import entities](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-import). The entire skill / workspace as well as the intents and entities can be exported.

That way, if you already have skills or their intents and entities, you could reuse them with IBM Watson Assistant.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I need many dialogs to check whether our coding could be applied to many dialog flows..

Comment: Although you could use the same training questions to create the same intents on both systems, the method of getting them into the respective systems is different. As mentioned above you can import them into the Watson workspace.
For Alexa they use slots, Watson assistant uses entities, but they are similar in the respective functions. Alexa has many more system "entities" than watson. So these would be hard to include. 
With regard to the dialog elements, here is where the systems differ - Alexa you need to program your responses, with Watson you use the watson tooling.